# Data in Workbench to Wave Dataset

Tags: einstein-analytics, workbench

How can I get a dataset in Wave Analytics if I have a query in Workbench?

I mean how to export that data to a dataset without using .csv format

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can use connectors or traditional dataflow editor and build the flow to get data.
for more information regarding dataflow and dataset creation you can refer to https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=bi_integrate_workflow_overview.htm&type=5